# HTML Button filtering based on two conditions

Tags: javascript, html, typescript

I have a button that is named "atCloudBttn", when you click it, it filters my data by status by all data that is pending.

How could I make this button also filter by another condition. The other condition would be IO by yes so, ('IO', 'Yes')?

```
<button role="button" name="atCloudBttn" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="changeFilter('Status', 'Pending')">
```

The change filter functions code is written in Typescript and I have included it below. I'm not 100% sure if I have to edit this code as well to reflect the change in structure.

```
ChangeFilter(field: string, term: string) {
this.filteredtable = true;
var filter = {};
filter[field] = term;
var title = ' ';
var activeColDef = this.columnDefs;
```

Comment: This totally depends on the change filter function you implemented.

Comment: ```
ChangeFilter(field: string, term: string) {
this.filteredtable = true;
var filter = {};
filter[field] = term;
var title = ' ';
var activeColDef = this.columnDefs;
```
This is the TypeScript function that is called for the change filter function

Comment: You could add data-attributes and read them in the click

Comment: @mplungjan what would that look like in this case? I haven't had to use data-attributes yet while learning so any help would be very much so appreciated.

Comment: something like `<button data-io="yes"` using `const io = e.currentTarget.dataset.io;`

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you write these two condition in a js function
and use `click="functionname()"` or add `.addEventListener("click",functionname());`

Comment: The change filter is a Typescript function and is used for multiple different buttons,

 
```
ChangeFilter(field: string, term: string) {
this.filteredtable = true;
var filter = {};
filter[field] = term;
var title = ' ';
var activeColDef = this.columnDefs;
```

Comment: Hi codingcat, what would it look like to write these two conditions as a js function? Lets say the functionname is "Happy" for this example.